# AdMob displaying 'Advertising tracking is disabled' even when tracking is enabled - how to retrieve Advertising Identifier?

Tags: admob, ads

I am facing a problem for admob display the adds advertising id is required when i run this code after permission

it always return nil which is "Advertising tracking is disabled" even i did enable the tracking but i can not get the advertising id anyone can help me.Thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
        self.requestTrackingPermission()
```

}

```
func requestTrackingPermission() {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            // Handle the user's response to the tracking authorization request
            if status == .authorized {
                // User granted permission, proceed to get the Advertising Identifier
                if let advertisingId = self.getAdvertisingIdentifier() {
                    print("Advertising Identifier: \(advertisingId)")
                } else {
                    print("Unable to retrieve Advertising Identifier.")
                }
            } else {
                // User denied permission, handle accordingly
                print("User denied permission for tracking.")
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}


func getAdvertisingIdentifier() -> String? {
    guard ASIdentifierManager.shared().isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled else {
        return nil // Advertising tracking is disabled
    }

    return ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
}
```